# Why won't the following java code compile?

Tags: java, exception

Quite Frankly, I'm just not understanding what my instructor is asking me to do here.  I've tried using "try - catch" blocks, as well as throws Exception in the method signature.  I've read about checked and unchecked exceptions. I'm sure this will get voted down or closed, but can someone throw me a bone here?  My instructors instructions are as follows:

"Correct it so it compiles."

```
class Exception3{
    public static void main(String[] args){         
    if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) == 0)             
        throw new Exception("Invalid Command Line Argument");     
     } 
}
```

It's obvious that it is throwing a RuntimeException.  More Specifically  an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  I know the cause of the exception is because the array is empty, so the referenced index doesn't exist. I mean, technically I could just erase `if(Integer.parseInt(args[0]) == 0)` and `throw new Exception("Invalid Command Line Argument");` and replace it with `System.out.println("It compiles now");`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{         
    if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) == 0)             
        throw new Exception("Invalid Command Line Argument");     
     }
```

Your method throwing `Exception`, so method declaration should specify that it may throw `Exception`.

As per [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

> Checked exceptions are subject to the Catch or Specify Requirement. All exceptions are checked exceptions, except for those indicated by Error, RuntimeException, and their subclasses.

Comment: That's it?  That's all I had to do?

Comment: LMAO!  That was the first thing I did like 2 hours ago!  The reason I've been so frustrated, and decided to come here, was because I got this when I ran the damn thing.                                                                                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: Compile time is different from Runtime. ArrayIndexOutofbounds is Runtime exception. If I understand your professor correctly, he/she was just looking for succesful compilation.

Comment: Your program will run without any issues if you run by passing a parameter with value other than 0.

Comment: Well, I do appreciate your time on this, and thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to either catch it using a try catch statement:

```
class Exception3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) == 0)
                throw new Exception("Invalid Command Line Argument");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

or declare it at the method header:

```
class Exception3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) == 0)
            throw new Exception("Invalid Command Line Argument");
    }
}
```